# The interpretor for Perl is written in C and yet perl is faster for string matching compared to C

Tags: c, perl

The interpreter for Perl is written in C and yet perl is faster for string matching compared to C. Can some one correct me if I am wrong. And if its a fact can this be explained?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered with respect to C since Perl is based on C. It's rather a question of the used algorithms just because C has no built in string processing features. Those are always added in terms of libraries or your own code.

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for this site as it stands.  Can you link to an example that shows perl being faster at string matching?

Comment: What kind of string matching? What is the input, what are we comparing? Which C compailer is used? What was the algorithm used in C?

Comment: Bicycle tire is bigger than car tire. Then why car is faster?

Comment: @NeonGlow Because bicyclists tire faster.

Comment: @TLP : Wish there was an option for selecting this as answer. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl is indeed written in C (and in Perl, I suppose).

C has no string matching ability, so it can't possibly be slower (or faster) than Perl's. Sure, you can write a string matching library in C and compare it to string matching in Perl, but you can't compare C's since C doesn't have one.

---

demerphq (one's of Perl's regex engine gurus) recently replied to "What is the speed (I won't define that) of P5 RE vs other RE in other languages?" with the following:

> This is a tricky question.  My general experience is that some regex engines match faster for some patterns, but that many regex engines *fail* to match slower, often much slower and that in practice perls engine is competitive or superior to many other engines. So you have to be really careful with benchmarks on this, many only look at a success cases, which Perl often is slower at.  This is a deliberate design decision, in many scenarios pattern fail to match more often than they match, and generally we try to fail fast.
>
> Another subject that makes this kind of comparison tricky is that Perls regex engine has a very rich feature set and other engines often trade features for performance. Perls regex engine has very good unicode support, support that you will often find is not supported by other engines (often this is despite their claims.)
>
> An example of this kind of stuff is the "mandatory substring" logic that Perl uses. The engine will find the longest string in the pattern that must be present for the pattern to match. We then use Fast-Boyer-Moore (FBM) matching to determine if the string exists. If it does not then we never start the regex engine. This means that in theory Perl can reject a pattern significantly faster than a true DFA could, and that in practice it often does so. A DFA typically needs to do N operations for a string of length N, FBM can do best case N/L inspections, where N is the number of characters and L is the length of the mandatory string.

Comment: I assumed that you were referring to the regex engine rather than `index` when you say "string matching ability".

Comment: There are (very simple) regular expressions for which Perl takes [exponential time](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) to match a string against, while a DFA always takes linear time. So Perl's string matching is actually horrendously slow in the worst case.

Answer (score 4):

Perl's string matching code doesn't have to use C's (handful of) string-handling library functions. Therefore it's not limited by the choice of algorithm of the C library implementer, it can make its own decisions.

I suppose my answer is that there's no reason Perl's string-matching shouldn't be faster than a given C implementation's, just because Perl is implemented in C. Whether it actually *is* faster, I don't know.

Comment: Neither do C programs have to use the libc string functions, but on most impls they're hard to beat...

Comment: @R..: well, it's entirely possible that the questioner is mistaken, and for example Perl's `index` does not in fact beat `strstr` (on his implementation, blah blah). But if it does then I'm pretty certain it's because it doesn't call `strstr` ;-) As for C programs not having to call `strstr`, of course you're right but the only vague sense I can make of this question is if it's trying to compare performance of standard (or at least commonly-used) library functions.

Comment: ... and in a straight fight between the Perl implementers and the glibc implementers to match a substring as fast as possible, I have no particular grounds to pick one over the other. ikegami has already spoken about Perl's regex engine, and similarly whoever wrote Perl's regexes may well have beaten whoever wrote (for example) glibc's regexes. At least for whatever cases the questioner tried.

Comment: FWIW, glibc's strstr is the state-of-the-art algorithm for strstr. It's essentially impossible to beat except for a stupid detail that's making short needles suboptimal.

Comment: @R..: fair enough. Same argument, Microsoft's `strstr`. In whatever ancient version of msvcrt the questioner might have ;-)